# Prevent Hardcoding Routerlink

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

Is there an approach in order to prevent hard coding routerlink in each component.html?

Having this code

```
<a [routerLink]="['/home/candoy/pipeline/', this.Id]">Pipeline</a><br />
<a [routerLink]="['/home/candoy/filter/', this.Id]">Filter</a><br />
```

at 5+ different component page.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No, that's what Angular is for!

When you use [square brackets] for a property in Angular, you can pass any variable from your component into that parameter. This means that you can also loop through an array of pre-set items. Here's an example:

```
<span *ngFor="let item of menuItems"><a [routerLink]="[item.route, this.Id]">{{item.title}}</a><br /></span>
```

And then in your component.ts:

```
menuItems = [{ route: '/home/candoy/pipeline', title: 'Pipeline'}, { route: '/home/candoy/filter', title: 'Filter'}]
```

**What about sharing between components?**

Well, your menu should really be a component on its own, and then you can just include the menu into the other components.

BUT - if you really need to do this, you can put the array into a **service**, import the service into your component (as public) and then access the array from the template.